# How to draw shape div with css?

Tags: html, css

I need to draw shapes as shown here in the  image

[image]

All what I need is this example.

In top I want to set text, bottom input , but I don't have idea how to shape this ?

Using only css html ?

Maybe any css shape generator ?

I tried with:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  width: 30%;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.second {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="first">
    First
  </div>
  <div class="second">
   Second
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What determines the dimensions of the two "sections"? Is it their content or a set width/height or.....

Comment: You defined the class `.column` but you never use it your code, You also said that the second box should be an input so you should reflect this in the code of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```css
.left {
  width: 49px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.right {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: none;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper {
width: 150px;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```